# Crawl and Search only in one Sub Site not other Sites and Site Collection in SharePoint 2019 On Premise

Tags: search-results, enterprise-search, 2019, sharepoint-search

I have SharePoint 2019 On Premise and is there any way to crawl only one subsite and exclude the entire site collection.

I created a Content Source to point http://myportal/sites/teamsite but when i start full crawl i saw that whole site collection crawled.

am trying to configure search in such a way that when a user makes a search using the default search (documents, content from site pages etc..) only items from the subsite shows up in the results (http://myportal/teamsite).

Additionally, any items residing in the top site collection (http://myportal) should not be crawled or come up in the search result.